# PHP's DirectoryIterator is not reading file created with Linux

Tags: php, linux, encoding, iterator, touch

I'm experiencing an oddity with PHP's DirectoryIterator() function. I'm reading from a directory and can view all the .txt files I've saved using Windows (over an SMB share). However, if I create a .txt file using Linux (which is what PHP is running on), it simply does not read it. No error, just acts like it doesn't exist. If I open the file in Windows and resave it without making any changes, the file is suddenly able to be read.

I've tried using PHPs built in Touch() function, fopen(), and using shell_exec() and using Linuxs built-in touch command to create it, however none of that helped. I've tried changing the files permissions, owner, and group, and even executing PHP as root, just to see if it would work and no luck. I've also looked at the encoding of the files and both Linux and Windows are encoding them with UTF8, so that's not it.

Interestingly, if I take the file that doesn't work and move it out of the directory, then move it right back in, it works. So that leads me to believe maybe it's not the file per say, but the way it's being written? No clue.

Can someone please help me brainstorm some ideas? I have no clue why 2 seemingly identical files cannot be read by DirectoryIterator()

I'm running PHP 8 on Arch Linux and I'm using this code to read from the directory:

```
$path = "threads/";
$files = new DirectoryIterator($path);
$files_array = array();
                    
while($files->valid()) {
    $key = $files->getMTime();
    $data = $files->getFilename();
    $files_array[$key] = $data;
    $files->next();
}
rsort($files_array);

foreach ($files_array as $fileinfo) {
      echo $fileinfo;
}
```

And this code to create the text file:

```
touch ("../threads/" . $threadNumber . ".txt");
```

Comment: You need to post your code that creates the file and then uses the directory iterator.

Comment: I have added the code, sorry about that!

Comment: There is a whole lot of conjecture in the Q. We need actual testable code.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two parts of the script? Are you sure you're creating the file before you create the directory iterator?

Comment: I've discovered something. I included the entire code, and I believe it's happening when I'm doing the next step; Sorting them in reverse alphabetical order. Perhaps while($files->valid()) is not picking it up? If I don't sort, and read the directoryiterators output raw, it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, so I'm not sure what the issue was, but I assume it was something to do with `$files->valid()`

It seems like it wasn't reading the file as being valid. The documentation simply says "Check whether current DirectoryIterator position is a valid file". I ended up just switching to using scandir() and it works perfectly now. Very odd.

If someone could shed some light on this, that would be great